# How to use ts-nameof in the gulp build chain, getting: Unknown compiler option 'getCustomTransformers'.?

Tags: typescript, gulp, gulp-typescript

I am using [ts-nameof](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-nameof) within my TypeScript files as like in this `.ts`-file:

```
import 'ts-nameof';

export class MyTsNameOfTest {
  public testTsNameOf() {
    const nameString = nameof(console.log);
  }
}
```

My Gulp build task - as recommended here [Gulp configuration](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof/blob/master/setup/gulp.md):

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const tsNameof = require("ts-nameof");

gulp.task("typescript", function () {
  gulp.src("src/**/*.ts")
    .pipe(ts({
      getCustomTransformers: () => ({ before: [tsNameof] })
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
});
```

Running `gulp` I get error:

```
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'getCustomTransformers'.
```

Versions I am using:

```
gulp 3.9.1
gulp-typescript 3.2.4
typescript 2.9.2
ts-nameof 2.0.0
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Update `gulp-typescript` to at least `5.0.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preparation

Install required `npm` packages

```
npm install typescript
npm install gulp@^4.0.0                
npm install gulp-typescript@^5.0.0
npm install del
npm install ts-nameof
```

### `gulp-typescript` WITHOUT a project

Prepare `gulpfile.js`

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const tsNameof = require("ts-nameof");
const del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', () => {
    return del(['./dist/**']);
});    

gulp.task('ts', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts({
            getCustomTransformers: () => ({ before: [tsNameof] })
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('default',
    gulp.series(
        'clean',
        'ts',
    ));
```

### `gulp-typescript` WITH a project using existing `tsconfig.json`

Using `gulp-typescript` with an existing `tsconfig.json` the `gulpfile.js` must be adjusted where the option `getCustomTransformers` is configured:

Prepare `gulpfile.js`

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const ts = require('gulp-typescript');
const tsNameof = require("ts-nameof");
const del = require('del');

gulp.task('clean', () => {
    return del(['./dist/**']);
}); 

var tsProject = tsProject || null;
gulp.task('ts::Project', function () {
    if (!tsProject) {
        tsProject = ts.createProject(
            'tsconfig.json',
            {
                getCustomTransformers: () => ({ before: [tsNameof] })
            }
        );
    }
    return gulp.src('./src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
});

gulp.task('tsProject',
    gulp.series(
        'clean',
        'ts::Project',
    ));
```

### Transpiling

Run `gulpfile.js` with

```
./node_modules/.bin/gulp
```

or

```
./node_modules/.bin/gulp tsProject
```

### Execution

Execute transpiled file `tsNameofTest.js`

```
node dist/tsNameofTest.js  // expected output: nameString: log
```

**Remark:** if `typescript` target is `ESNext` I got exectution errors with following statement in `.ts` file as it was in the final `.js` file, too:

```
import 'ts-nameof';
```

I got is fixed by replacing it with

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/ts-nameof/ts-nameof.d.ts" />
```

### Update

It is now even possible to install the type definition of `ts-nameof` globally:

```
npm install @types/ts-nameof --save-dev
```

Neither `import` nor `/// <reference path="" />` is neccessary.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I adjusted my answer but it still has your earlier comment attached. Should I have rather deleted this one and have created a new one?

Comment: nope, deleted my comment. your answer is very good by now. Always edit, don't del+repost.